# How should i do from notification back to activity without new intent

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-mediaplayer

from Android Development, i implement a simple notification by the sample code, but in my app, i don't want to new intent and create the activity again, i just want to back to my last activity(it's a mediaplayer UI). if i use the sample code, it will create a new activity by

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
```

i comment relative code about new intent and got a notification, but didn't have idea how to back to my last activity...

back to my app from long press home key and touch my app is OK. 
what i want is just like this behavior.

bleow is the sample code from Android Development, i comment the new intent portion.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
/*Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        0,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);*/
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

## [UPDATE]

i thought i need to set flag for intent and properity for activity.
therefore, for the activity i want to back to i set

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

and because, i don't want a new activity from intent, i just want my last activity, so i add

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY
```

from documentation i got that using **Pendingintent.contentIntent** it must include the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** flag and When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in. so i also add

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

but from logCat, i still saw that when i touch the notification for back to activity, the pendingintent still called onCreate() function rather than just show the last activity which still "alive".

Comment: i got an solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424488/android-new-intent-starts-new-instance-with-androidlaunchmode-singletop  
but no luck :(

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to call the Activity from background try this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourLauncherActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

If you click the Notification while on Homescreen the last shown Activity of your App will be get to the foreground without starting it new. If the Activity was killed by the system you will get a new Activity.

Comment: But the activity which backed by this way will separate from my original application :( 
i.e. activity(A) -> activity(B) at the same time do PendingIntent for B. When i back to B from notification, i can't return to A anymore...

Comment: That's strange. Are you still using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`?

Comment: yes. i didn't modified that. Do i need to set parentActivity for this Activity which used in PendingIntent?

Comment: i added the 
<meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="MY_LAUNCHERACTIVITY" /> for my minSDKVersion < 16 
but no luck, then tried add the TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);  but still no luck...
the situation like this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632480/android-build-a-notification-taskstackbuilder-addparentstack-not-working

Comment: anyway, thanks for your great help again. i think this is another problem i need to fix :)

Comment: @SteveBenett if the user swipes away my app from recent screens then clicks on a notification with this code in it, the app crashes. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I have used PendingIntent.getActivities instead of getActivity. This is working well in my project.

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                backIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);

                final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 1,
                        new Intent[] {backIntent, notificationIntent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, this worked :

> ```
> .setContentIntent(
>      PendingIntent.getActivity(
>      context,
>      0,
>      new Intent(context, YOUR_MAIN.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP ),PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT))
> ```
>
> FLAG_ONE_SHOT : DO NOT CREATE TWICE (associated with
>   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

Answer (score 1):

In `SingleTop` mode, I use this method without define explicitly the root activity class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
.setComponent(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName()).getComponent());
```

and this to resume last activity from notification:

```
builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0));
```

or this to resume last activity from a service:

```
try {
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0).send();
} catch (CanceledException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code hear

```
        Intent resultIntent = new 
 Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

        resultIntent.putExtra("splash",2);
        resultIntent.putExtra("message","test");
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationCompatBuilder.setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);
  
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
 
    if (extras != null) {
        String extraValue = extras.getString("notificationType");

        if(extraValue !=null){
            int value = Integer.parseInt(extraValue);
            if (value == 1) {
                intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("splash",value);
                intent.putExtra("message", "fromsplash");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else
             if (value == 2){
                 intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("swip","2");
                 intent.putExtra("message", "test");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } 
        } 

    } 
}
```