# Avoid the current activity finish when shart a notification

Tags: android

I want to start a notification in current `Activity` which is `ChatActivity`. When I press the notification, I want to enter the `ChatOneActivity`.

However I don't want the current `ChatActivity` finished when I'm in the `ChatOneActivity`. Because I'm receiving the data and when I press the back button, I want to stay in the `ChatActivity`.

The point is I do not want the `ChatActivity` to finish, no matter which `Activity` I am currently in.

So what should I do?

Here is the code

```
private void showNotification(String id, String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_email)
    .setContentTitle("You have a new message")
    .setContentText(message);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this,ChatOneActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("toId", id);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ChatActivity.this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatOneActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

The problem is:

Now I enter the `ChatOneActivity`and when I press the back button, I return to the desktop. Means that the `ChatActivity` has already finished which I don't want.

Here is the mainfest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webmobilegroupchat"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.webmobilegroupchat.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.webmobilegroupchat.ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.webmobilegroupchat.ChatOneActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_one" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.webmobilegroupchat.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Consider using a `Service` for these types of long running tasks.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with TaskStackBuilder.

Comment: Can you please show the manifest declaration for these `Activity`

Comment: I have added the manifest

Answer (score 1):

Try this on ChatOneActivity activity .

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChatActivity.Class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is looking fine for creating notification but you have to define parent activity in Manifest also to navigate back, `stackBuilder.addParentStack` assumes that you define it in Manifest as well for API 16+:

```
<activity android:name=".ChatOneActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ChatActivity"
    ... />
```

for < API 16:

```
<activity android:name=".ChatOneActivity">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".ChatActivity" />
```

Comment: Now when I press the back button,it return into ChatActivity. However the ChatActivity has finished.Is there any why can I avoid this?(if not use service)

Comment: not understand exactly, you want to navigate back to ChatActivity as you mentioned above in your question?

Comment: i mean your code looks fine .But when i press the notification, onDestory is called.And I don't know why .It means that the ChatActivity is killed by the system

Comment: It lookes like when you rotatethe screen ,it will invoke onDestory and onCreate .These method are called by the system. And I didn't invoke the finish method

Comment: yes while changing orientation it could be, you can confirm it by lock the orientation in one mode portrait/landscape & remember to accept the question if its helpful to you

Comment: but I didn'tchange the orientation...just start an activity

Comment: you probably need to check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425108/how-should-i-do-from-notification-back-to-activity-without-new-intent