# unable to open second notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I wanted to open different articles in one activity using different post id's which i am sending via notification. and i am able to open one post on clicking on notification but with same activity open i m unable to open or process second notification.

```
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
    if (sharedPref.getNotification()) {
        // play vibration
        if (sharedPref.getVibration()) {
            ((Vibrator) getSystemService( Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VIBRATION_TIME);
        }
        RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(sharedPref.getRingtone())).play();
        JSONObject json = null;

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            FcmNotif fcmNotif = new FcmNotif();
            fcmNotif.setTitle(data.get("title"));
            fcmNotif.setPosttitle( data.get("posttitle"));
            fcmNotif.setPost_id(data.get("post_id"));
            fcmNotif.setPost_slug( data.get( "post_slug" ) );
            fcmNotif.setCat_name(data.get("cat_name"));
            fcmNotif.setType(data.get("type"));
            if(!data.get("cat_name").equals("No Notification"))
            {
                displayNotificationIntent(fcmNotif);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void displayNotificationIntent(FcmNotif fcmNotif) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    if (fcmNotif.getPost_id() != "tnd") {
        intent = new Intent(this, PostDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra( "PostId",fcmNotif.getPost_id());
        intent.putExtra( "type",fcmNotif.getType() );
        intent.putExtra( "PostSlug",fcmNotif.getPost_slug() );
        intent.putExtra("CategoryName",fcmNotif.getCat_name());

    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(fcmNotif.getTitle());
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(fcmNotif.getPosttitle()));
    builder.setContentText(Html.fromHtml(fcmNotif.getPosttitle()));
    builder.setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.custom_icon);
    builder.setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    {
         builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    }
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int unique_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    notificationManager.notify(unique_id, builder.build());
}
```

Note: 
I have tried using `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` and it opens all notifications easily but when pressing HOME button and reopening app from drawer its opens first notification post not last opened one.

and XML is simple `

```
        android:name=".PostDetails"
        android:label="@string/back"
        android:parentActivityName=".AllCategoryList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got solution:

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                backIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);

                final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 1,
                        new Intent[] {backIntent, notificationIntent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

[from ans from diffrent question of @Jitendra ramoliya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671371/3185267)