# Android: Navigate to current back stack when handling notification

Tags: android, back-stack

I have a problem with navigating to current back stack when handling notification.
I have two activities, activity A called activity B, the current back stack is A, B.
After that, I tap to Home button -> Navigate to Home screen. At that time, my application receives a notification. When handling that notification, I want to open my application with back stack is A, B and B keeps current its state.

Which way can I solve this problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html . check **Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity.**

Comment: If activity A calls activity C, and activity C calls activity D, and also activity A can call activity B, how to solve this case? (Whether current activity is B or D, I want to keep current back stack.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In Manifest set [android:launchMode="singleTask"](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for ActivityB.
2. In your Notification set PendingIntent that will call ActivityB.

Comment: If activity A calls activity C, and activity C calls activity D, and also activity A can call activity B, how to solve this case? (Whether current activity is B or D, I want to keep current back stack.)

Comment: @user2298077 , Sorry?
If ActivityB is on top of backstack then you will show ActivityB and the backstack will not changed. But if ActivityB is not on top of backstack then backstack will change - all activities that have been created after ActivityB will be destroyed. If you don't have ActivityB in backstack then only ActivityB will open.

Comment: Maybe you need to use this for your second situation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13632559/1001401