# Up Navigation on Action Bar closes app in Android. Inactive Input Connection

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-actionbar, up-navigation

Up Navigation on Action Bar closes app in Android. Followed android developer exactly. I added .getSupportActionBar,.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled, inflated my menu, put my case in onCreateOptionsMenu but is still doesn't work.

```
public class AddressList extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_address_list);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_address_list, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Add();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is my manifest file to show that I've added parentactivity name and the metadata.

```
  <activity
   android:name=".SilentGeofence"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_silent_geofence"
        android:parentActivityName=".AddressList" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".AddressList" />

    </activity>
```

Comment: Do you receive any error msg?

Comment: 03-12 19:35:00.529  16221-16221/com.example.anusha.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection @joaquin

Comment: Well, your Log is absolutely incomplete. But it seems to be that the problem is not on the code you posted.

Comment: I know it's a bit old, but, well, what struck me first is that you show us code for `AddressList(Activity)`, and then you show in Manifest it's a PARENT for `SilentGeofence`. Shouldn't the code snippet be in `SilentGeofence` actually?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue previously. Try using the following code snippet. Credit goes to the link in the snippet:

```
case android.R.id.home:

            //solution for the up navigation problem:
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632480/android-build-a-notification-taskstackbuilder-addparentstack-not-working
            Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
                // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
                TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                        // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                                // Navigate up to the closest parent
                        .startActivities();
            } else {
                // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
                // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
                upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
                Log.v("recreate activity", "shouldUpRecreateTask = false");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in android:value try to use full package name of parent Activity

```
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.AddressList" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still needs an answer here is how I was able to do it.

```
//First set Parent activity in your xml as shown above


<activity
       android:name=".ChildActivity"
            android:label="@string/title"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />

        </activity>

//Now you can simply get the parent Intent and use startActivity
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent upIntent=NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
//You might need to add some Launch Parameters like
                upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(upIntent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

You can find more Information about these launch parameters here:
[Launch Parameter Info](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)