# Maintain Parent Activity on Push Notifications Event

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I have an Activity A (Splash Activity), Activity B (Home Activity), Activity C(Offers Activity), Activity D (Miscellaneous Activity). I want to create appropriate Landings to Offers Activity in two scenarios:

General App flow:
**Activity A-> Activity B -> Activity C-> Activity D**

**Scenario A**: When the application is closed. (Not exist in the task manager)
**Requirement**: On Clicking the Push Notification, I want the user should land directly to Activity C (Offers Activity). And I want that on clicking back button the user should not exit from the application, rather he should be able to see Activity A and then clicking back from A, he should exit.
**Current Scenario:** Right now, when notification lands,on clicking to it, user land to Activity C (that is right), but on clicking back from that screen, the user directly exits from the application. Why this is so ? Here is my parentactivity stack code

```
          <activity
            android:name=".OffersActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.zotopay.zoto.HomeActivity" />
         </activity>


         <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >
         </activity>


  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zotopay.zoto"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1310145
        versionName "1.4.5"
    }
```

**Push Notification Landing Code:**

```
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, OffersActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            // All the parents of OffersActivity will be added to task stack.
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(OffersActivity.class);
            // Add a SecondActivity intent to the task stack.
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong? because of which I get exited from the application when press back from the Offers Activity rather than landing to HomeActivity.

Comment: In manifest you should add parentActivityName attribute for your Activity C. And for older devices metaData child <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ui.MainActivity" />

Comment: pff, where is parentActivityName ???

Comment: official docs on these two http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent

Comment: @ViktorYakunin are you not able to see <meta-tag> for my OffersActivity. It is the same thing.

Comment: So should I add  that too ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111513/discussion-between-gaurav-arora-and-viktor-yakunin).

Comment: not answered yet, can anyone please help

Comment: I've created small project, to prove it works https://github.com/BukT0p/ActivityTaskBuilder

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13632559/3746306)

Comment: Flag Cancel Current is the same as that of Flag update current @ViktorYakunin ?

Comment: Not the same, but similar, it doesn't affect the stack logic

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Can you come on chat for 5 mins